# Why does HttpResponse have Redirect methods?

Tags: asp.net-core

- Why have these particular configurations of a HTTP Response been promoted to be a first class concept?
- Why is location a string, and not a URI?
- How do I do a 302 vs a 303 vs a 307?
- Will 301 be always the return value if permanent is true?  What about when 308 becomes standardized?

Comment: Don't you think all asp.net-vnext question you've asked fit better to be asked on http://github.com/aspnet?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I started there, but the instructions regarding github issues was that it should be limited to "bugs".  Stackoverflow was a suggested alternative.

Comment: hmm, I though they'd changed that. Anyway, seems like you're right posting that question here, as they asked to do. But I'm still a little concerned, that SO is not a good place for this kind of questions.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yeah, seems like they are a bit too opinionated for SO.

Comment: I'd suggest joining the discussion JabbR: https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/AspNetvNext